# Problema com rotas Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação na qual eu coloquei como um novo site e funcionou direitinho, mas ao colocar essa aplicação dentro de outra, da um erro na rota.
Preciso que ao fazer login, direcione para "http://localhost:porta/Documentos/PainelAdm" e ele está direcionando para "http://localhost:porta/PainelAdm".
Trecho onde retorna para a view "PainelAdm":

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(FormCollection f, string returnUrl)
        {
            Conta user = new Conta();
            ContaModels atrrConta = new ContaModels();
            atrrConta = user.RetornaUser(f["login"]); 
            if (user.AutenticaUser(atrrConta, f["senha"]))
            {
                //Rotina para autenticar usuario
                if (returnUrl == "" || returnUrl == null)
                {
                    returnUrl = "/CalendarioAlertaSMS";
                }

                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(atrrConta.Ide_Perfil.ToString(), false); 

                Session["PERFIL"] = atrrConta.Ide_Perfil;
                Session["NOME"] = atrrConta.Nome;

                if (Session["PERFIL"].ToString() == "ADMIN")
                {
                     returnUrl = "/PainelAdm"; 
                }

                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Login ou senha inválidos.";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Defina "colocar aplicação dentro de outra". O que seria isso?

Comment: Você fez alguma modificação no RouteConfig.cs ? Ou está usando o padrão?

Comment: Se possível, edite a questão adicionando o código do seu RouteConfig.cs, imagino que você esteja fazendo algo errado nele.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Cara aquele meu problema eu consegui resolver, agora o problema é, tipo, tenho um site em asp classico que através de um botão irá chamar uma outra aplicação em asp.net mvc. E eu coloquei essa aplicação em mvc dentro do site que está em asp classico. Preciso que ele abra através desse site em asp classico.

Comment: @Intruso, não, não fiz nenhuma alteração, só tem um trecho onde eu estou verificando o perfil de usuário, que se ele tiver o perfil de administrador ele retorna uma Home diferente de usuários que não tem esse perfil, e é nesse ponto que eu estou passando essa que eu mencionei na pergunta.

Comment: @AndreeH Isso é muito tosco. Eu colocaria cada site em um subdomínio diferente. As rotas em MVC não são diretórios, e naturalmente o IIS se perde na hora de resolver os nomes.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Beleza, tenho isso feito, mas como consigo fazer com que o botão do site asp classico chame essa aplicação mvc ?

Comment: @AndreeH Faça uma requisição *hard*, sem caminhos relativos. Não deixa de ser outro site em outro lugar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, pode me dar um exemplo de como faço isso ?

Comment: Ué, um link para http://meusite:porta/

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Puts, já tentei isso e não foi. :S

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez também não funciona, cara, só preciso que redirecione assim "http://lmeu_site:porta/Documentos/PainelAdm". Como posso definir uma rota para isso que funcione no iis ?

Comment: Subdomínios diferentes quer dizer diretórios virtuais diferentes. Você não entendeu esta parte?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Uma aplicação MVC quando colocada dentro de outra, não funciona mesmo, para que funcione converta a pasta da aplicação interna em um um aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara, eu fiz isso, eu tenho uma aplicação independente que funciona perfeitamente, mas ao colocar ela para ser chamada dentro de um site em asp classico não está funcionando. O problema é com a rota.